# multiple errors when running code, "value of type PNConfiguration has no member stripMobilePayload"

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub

```
  import UIKit

  class ConnectVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var usernname: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func buttonclicked(_ sender: Any) {
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "connectSegue", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
//Accessing Nav Controller and ChannelVC view
if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
    let channelVC = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? channelvc{
    var usernname = ""
    var password = ""
    //Replacing empty values with default ones
    if(usernname.text == "" ){
        usernname = "A Naughty Moose"
    }

    }
    if(password.text == "" ){
        print("nothing in channel")
        channel = "General"
    }
    else{
        channel = password.text ?? "General"
    }
    //Setting values in ChannelVC
    channelvc.usernname = usernname
    channelvc.password = password
}
}
```

hello, so im making a chat app, when i clean build my project, all the errors go away, however when i run the code, all the errors pop up,

```
    import UIKit
     import PubNub
   class channelvc: UIViewController,PNObjectEventListener, UITableViewDataSource, 
   UITableViewDelegate {
  struct Message {
   var messages: String
   var username: String
   var uuid: String
 }
  let configuration = PNConfiguration(publishKey: "pub-c-redacted", subscribeKey: "sub-c-redacted")

   configuration.stripMobilePayload = false
 //Making each connection identifiable for future development
configuration.uuid = UUID().uuidString
client = PubNub.clientWithConfiguration(configuration)
client.addListener(self)
client.subscribeToChannels([channelName],withPresence: true)
//We load the last messages to populate the tableview
 loadLastMessages()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell") as! MessageCell
    cell.messageLabel.text = messages[indexPath.row].password
    cell.usernameLabel.text = messages[indexPath.row].usernname
    return cell
}
func publishMessage() {
    if(messageTextField.text != "" || messageTextField.text != nil){
        let messageString: String = messageTextField.text!
        let messageObject : [String:Any] =
            [
                "message" : messageString,
                "username" : usernname,
                "uuid": client.uuid()
        ]
        client.publish(messageObject, toChannel: channelName) { (status) in
            print(status.data.information)
       }
        messageTextField.text = ""
    }
}

var messages: [Message] = []
//Keep track of the earliest message we loaded
var earliestMessageTime: NSNumber = -1
 //To keep track if we are already loading more messages
var loadingMore = false
//Our PubNub object that we will use to publish, subscribe, 
and get the history of our channel
var client: PubNub!
//Temporary values
var channelName = "Channel Name"
var usernname = "Username"

override func viewDidLoad() {
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = channelName
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    loadLastMessages()
     super.viewDidLoad()



   //Where our messages come in




     }
     func loadLastMessages()
     {
     addHistory(start: nil, end: nil, limit: 10)
    //Bring the tableview down to the bottom to the most recent messages
    if(!self.messages.isEmpty){
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.messages.count-1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}



 @IBAction func sendbutton(_ sender: Any) {
     publishMessage(
  }
@IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!
@IBAction func leavechannel(_ sender: Any) {
}

 func addHistory(start:NSNumber?,end:NSNumber?,limit:UInt){
    //The PubNub Function that returns an object of X messages, and when the first and last. 
 messages were sent.
      //The limit is how many messages are received with a maximum and default of 100.
    client.historyForChannel(channelName, start: start, end: end, limit:limit){ (result, status) in
        if(result != nil && status == nil){
            //We save when the earliest message was sent in order to get ones previous to it when we want to load more.
            self.earliestMessageTime = result!.data.start
            //Convert the [Any] package we get into a dictionary of String and Any
            let messageDict = result!.data.messages as! [[String:String] {

           //Creating new messages from it and putting them at the end of messages array
           var newMessages :[Message] = []
            for m in messageDict{
               let message = Message(message: m["message"]! , usernname: m["usernname"]!, uuid: m["uuid"]! )
            newMessages.append(message)
        }
            self.messages.insert(contentsOf: newMessages, at: 0)
            //Reload the table with the new messages and bring the tableview down to the bottom to the most recent messages
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        //Making sure that we wont be able to try to reload more data until this is completed.
        self.loadingMore = false
    }
    else if(status !=  nil){
        print(status!.category)
    }
    else{
        print("everything is nil whaaat")
    }
  [enter image description here][1] }
 }

} func client(_ client: PubNub, didReceiveMessage message: PNMessageResult) {
//Whenever we receive a new message, we add it to the end of our messages array and
//reload the table so that it shows at thebottom.
if(channelName == message.data.channel)
{
    let m = message.data.message as! [String:String]
    self.messages.append(Message(message: m["message"]!, username: m["username"]!, uuid: 
m["uuid"]!))
    tableView.reloadData()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: messages.count-1, section: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
}
print("Received message in Channel:",message.data.message!)
}

      func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
      //If we are not loading more messages already
      if(!loadingMore){
       //-40 is when you have dragged down from the top of all the messages
       if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < -40 ) {
         loadingMore = true
         addHistory(start: earliestMessageTime, end: nil, limit: 10)
      }
    }
   }

   client.unsubscribeFromAll()
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "leaveChannelSegue", 
   sender: self)
    }
```

im getting errors such as "value of type PNConfiguration has no member stripMobilePayload"

[image]

I followed a tutorial online https://www.pubnub.com/blog/how-to-build-ios-mobile-group-chat-app-swift-5-pubnub/ i followed it step by step but im still getting alot of error

Comment: I redacted your pub and sub keys. You may want to disable that key set and create a new key set. Try to keep from posting those in the public, at lease until you enable Access Manager on the key set in PubNub account.

Comment: In your post, I do not see any errors that are specifically PubNub errors including the stripMobilePayload config property you are referencing. You should be able to just remove it from your code completely but please share the errors that are specific to this property. And which version of PubNub Swift SDK are you using (what's declared in your podfile)?

Comment: so i should remove stripMobilePayload config from my code? im using swift 5 and xcode and pod “PubNub”, “~> 4”

Comment: so it looks like you are using our [old Swift SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk) which is really just wrapper for Obj-C SDK. If you want native Swift, use our [new Swift SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift-native/pubnub-swift-sdk).

Comment: but that stripMobilePayload, may not even affect you. If it does, let us know. You can contact [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) directly if you like. It's free (for most things) and fast (no guaranteed response time like paid support but still fast, typically). Include link to this post if you do reach out to them.